# GameObject to appear when clicking a button in unity3d?

Tags: c#, uibutton, unity-game-engine

I needed to create **UIButton** attached to a gameobject.

I'm using a board based game i.e., when ever clicking a button at that time place one object to that particular button.

I am using c# script in `unity3d` .

```
    void UIBtn(GameObject BName)
     {
       //here to write Button click event.
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean GUI.Button .

Reading your first sentence I understood that you wanted to create a button where a GameObject is, but reading your second sentence it seems that you want a GameObject to appear when clicking a button. Since I'm not sure, I'll answer both.

To make a GUI button appear at the place the mouse is use something like:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnGUI() {
        Vector2 screenPos = Event.current.mousePosition;
        GUI.Button ( new Rect(screenPos.x,screenPos.y,100,100),"Hello");
}

}
```

Attaching a button to a GameObject requires first identifying the GameObject via Physics.Raycast and then getting the GameObject from the HitCollider and then, on the game object's OnGUI loop. constantly translate its world coordinates to screen coordinates to be able to show a button, via GUI.Button.

Comment: ya , i needed second sentence answer of your post but i'm using ngui buttons , i'm trying to this get null refernce exception i.e - NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object , i'm new member of unity so plz help me how to solve the aboe problem